# Стоит ли выбирать Python первым языком?

Tags: python

Всем привет! Уже очень давно хотел открыть для себя программирование и возник такой вопрос: Прочитав много разнообразных статейб понялб что авторы сходятся на изучения Python как первого языка. В то время, мои знакомые говорят что лучше начать изучать C. Хотелось бы узнать ваше мнение.

Comment: По информатике в школе сначала знакомят с Visual Basic, в моем университете 1 семестр тоже он был, думаю стоит начать с него. Вообще вам стоит уточнить для чего вам понадобилось программирование- знаете, забивать гвозди лучше молотком, а не отверткой.

Comment: Я начал с питона и вообще не жалею. Простой, понятный, развивающийся. Применяется во многих областях.

Comment: Имхо. Да. Если изучаете самостоятельно

Comment: Я вот вообще начинал с QBasic, успел перепробовать Visual Basic, Pascal, Delphi, C++, Python. Как мне кажется, для старта Python - идеальный вариант. Хотя это, конечно, смотря какие у вас аппетиты и сроки.

Comment: Питон для обучения **вреден**, потому что маскирует детали реализации, приучает к плюшкам, отсутствующим в других языках, имеет утиную типизацию

Comment: @andreymal: для того чтобы успешно большинство задач решать с помощью программирования, не нужно знать что такое транзистор, из чего состоит, как разные логические винтили из транзисторов можно составить, как из вентилей различные элементы типа сумматоров можно сделать, как из них более сложные элементы комбинируются, чтобы универсальное вычислительное устройство получить, итд. Как известно любая проблема в IT может быть решена введением дополнительного уровня абстракции. [Программирование в той же степени о компьютерах, как астрономия о телескопах](https://goo.gl/MPUjGn)

Comment: @jfs а вот для того, чтобы понимать, к̶а̶к̶о̶г̶о̶ ̶х̶р̶е̶н̶а̶ ̶э̶т̶о̶ ̶в̶с̶ё̶ ̶о̶п̶я̶т̶ь̶ ̶н̶е̶ ̶р̶а̶б̶о̶т̶а̶е̶т̶ как и почему оно работает и, как следствие, как это всё можно оптимально применять, а не фигак-фигак и в продакшен, — очень даже нужно. *(А ещё вы тактично умолчали, что дополнительной абстракцией нельзя решить проблему слишком большого числа абстракций :)*

Comment: А также для большей простоты перехода на более строгие языки типа той же джавы (а то будет очень сложно переходить, привыкнув к тому, что поля в класс можно добавлять на лету или что функции класса-родителя без проблем видят поля, объявленные только в классах-потомках, или что int не такой уж и бесконечный)

Comment: @andreymal я мягко намекал, что уровней абстракций много в реальных системах—никто не знаком детально со всеми.  Видео по ссылке явно упоминает основную проблему, с которой программисты борются (сложность) и основной ограничитель (человеческие мозги). Чтобы понять *суть* программирования, чтобы как можно быстрее реальные задачи на практике решать — Питон позволяет забыть о несущественных деталях¶ Я как человек, который о компьютере в терминах Си думает, хорошо понимаю откуда   приходите—иногда настолько уровень абстракции привычен, что с реальностью путаешь.

Answer (score 4):

`Python` в качестве первого языка полезен хотя бы тем, что заставляет более-менее нормально форматировать код с отступами.

В `C` компилятор проглотит любое форматирование, что может выработать неправильные привычки. Кроме того некоторым начинающим с трудом даётся концепция работы с указателями...

Answer (score 2):

Решительно Python против C, потому что в Питоне (кроме других полезных вещей):

- не нужно *предварительно определить* переменные,
- есть много *вставленных полезных* типов переменных, как списки или словари, а не только целые числа, реальные числа и знак, как в C,
- напишете *одной командой наглядно* то, что в C многими,
- сразу можете писать полезные программы, а не только "Hello, world!",
- *сразу* можете в интерактивном режиме попробовать команды (без компиляции),
- ввод / вывод с консоли или с файлов чрезвычайно простые,
- *отличная документация*, интерактивная, в PDF и он-лайн, всё бесплатно.

Answer (score 1):

Не слушайте ваших друзей. C язык сложный язык и для профессионалов. Начнете его изучение - столкнетесь с массой сложностей, утонете в терминах и тонкостях языка.

Python прекрасно подходит для  закладки фундамента при изучении чего-то более сложного, при этом не уступает своим "старшим" собратьям по функциональности. Однако можете обратить внимание на Visual Basic или Pascal